# WCF - maxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I have a problem setting `maxReceivedMessageSize` for larger files.

I'm getting:

> The maximum message size quota for
>   incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use
>   the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on
>   the appropriate binding element.

Here is my server side configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="HTTPBaseAddress" value="http://localhost:8080/WelcomeMessage/"/>
    <add key="HTTPFileTransferAddress" value="http://localhost:8080/FileTransfer/"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="FS.Services.MessageService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint contract="FS.Interfaces.IMessageService" address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
    </service>
      <service name="FS.Services.FileTransferService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint contract="FS.Interfaces.IFileTransferService" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamedHttpBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="streamedHttpBinding" 
                 messageEncoding="Text" 
                 transferMode="Streamed" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="400000000"/>
       </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is my client side configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="FS.Services.IMessageService"
        name="FS.Services.MessageService" />
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamedHttpBinding"
        contract="FS.Services.IFileTransferService" name="FS.Services.FileTransferService" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="streamedHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="400000000"
          messageEncoding="Text" transferMode="Streamed"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is how i connect the client:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding2 = new BasicHttpBinding("streamedHttpBinding");
EndpointAddress endpoint2 = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8080/FileTransfer");
ChannelFactory<IFileTransferService> channelFactory2 = new ChannelFactory<IFileTransferService>(binding2, endpoint2);
IFileTransferService proxy2 = channelFactory2.CreateChannel();
((IClientChannel)proxy2).Open();
```

Also I would like to transfer any type of files up to 500mb using stream messages.
Can someone please provide me with configuration (or solution) that would support that?

Thanx!

Comment: sorry ... i have tried inserting the code, but only the first line appears...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client side config doesn't have any `<client>` tag that would reference the server, and to which you could apply the binding configuration with your increased message size......

On your **server** side, you need to define the service and its endpoints:

```
<services>
   <service name="YourNamespace.YourServiceClass">
       <endpoint name="endpoint1"
                 address="http://server:8888/YourService.svc" 
                 binding="basicHttpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="lageMessageTransfer"
                 contract="IYourServiceContract" />
   </service>
</services>
```

On your **client** side, you need to define your client endpoint connecting to one of the service endpoints

```
<client>
   <endpoint name="Default"
             address="http://server:8888/YourService.svc" 
             binding="basicHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="lageMessageTransfer"
             contract="IYourServiceContract" />
</client>
```

**Update:** ok, now I see your config fine - but **where** is your client endpoint connecting to?? You don't have any `address=` defined!

```
 <client>
    <endpoint name="FS.Services.FileTransferService" 
              address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="streamedHttpBinding"
              contract="FS.Services.IFileTransferService" />
 </client>
```

Comment: where would i put the client tag? I belive i would have to encapsulate services section with it?

Comment: im sorry i missplaced images !

Comment: looks like that is not the problem... any other idea?

Comment: The code works as im able to transfer small files both ways ... up and down. The problem is when i try to download/upload larger files. No matter how i set maxReceivedMessageSize i still get the same error.

Comment: @no9: maybe the problem doesn't even lie with WCF - maybe it's just IIS that gets in your way (has a limit of 4 MB for file transfer by default); check out: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits

Comment: probably so .. i will play some more with this problem :) Thanx for your time!